# Get laravel CSRF token from outside laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to post a search form from classic asp to a laravel route. I can get the csrf token from the cookie, if there is one and put it into the form, but I don't know what to do if there is no csrf cookie?

Should I open laravel route that returns new csrf token or is that a security risk?

Is the only other option to remove the route I need to post to from csrf validation?

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to send a post request to a Laravel app from a separate ASP.NET website?

Comment: @Bogdan yes, from a classic asp page...

Comment: if you want you can disable csrf token https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806762/how-to-disable-csrf-token-in-laravel-and-why-we-have-to-disable-it

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of using the CSRF tokens, no?

Comment: Since you are making a cross-site request (from asp to laravel), it doesn't make sense that you use CSRF protection for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable CSRF protection for specific route in `VerifyCsrfToken middleware`, you will find `$protected $except array` 
you can add the routes that will not be checked for CSRF Token

```
/**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        // for example
        "form/route"
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an API endpoint using something like tymondesigns/jwt-auth. You would then request a token first then submit your form to the API endpoint with the token.