# How to disable CSRF Token in Laravel and why we have to disable it?

Tags: laravel

I want to see how I can disable CSRF token in Laravel and where I have to disable it. Is this good to disable it or not?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can Disable CSRF on few routes by editing.

```
App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken
```

and add your own routes name in protected

```
$except = [] array.
```

It does not seems to be good practice as by doing this we are removing security feature of Laravel.

Comment: in my Laravel7 it's URIs and not route names (horrific design decision but well...)

Comment: @IceFire It is very easy to **convert route names to URIs** by using `route` helper for each element in the array in the `__construct` method.

Answer (score 43):

In laravel 10.
Open file `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php`

Disable for all routes

```
protected $except = [
    '*',
];
```

Disable for some routes

```
 protected $except = [
    'mobile/*',
    'news/articles',
];
```

I searched for a long time how to disable CSRF completely, there are many identical examples but they do not help

Comment: Disable for all routes is very useful for starter learning. thank u

Comment: no it is not. you should learn to use it. disabling it should never be an option.

Comment: @rameezmeans It should. Limiting a programmer because you assume he is doing the "wrong" thing is ridiculous and a snowflake approach to programming.

Comment: @Silidrone okay. so by disabling middleware we must invite security risk?

Comment: If one decides to invite a security risk to their own software, by all means, they should be able to. Discouraging it, I understand. Disallowing it? I don't agree with that.

Comment: it depends. What about when Laravel is used as a backend only app (ie API) and the frontend is a totally separate project that authenticate its request using some authentication method such as bearer token, jwt or other? in that case, is it really necessary the use of CSRF token?

Answer (score 30):

Many people explain how to do it, but they do not explain what the url should look like.

edit app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/user/my_function'
    ];
}
```

In the $except array(); we add a url with just a simple string.  This points to a controller usually depending on how your route is setup.

For example I have a UserController.php file in my Controller folder.  I have a route like. In the web.php routes file.

```
Route::post('/user', 'UserController@my_function')->name('my_function');
```

Also alternatively, if you came to this question simply because you don't know how to use the CSRF and you don't actually need to disable it, or make the URL except.  You can use this method.

Add these lines to your app.blade.php if it is used for ajax related calls.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 15):

You can disable it in `app/http/Kernel.php` in the `web` middleware group.

---

*Is this good to disable it or not?*

**No** it's not. Read the [Wikipedia page about CSRF](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site-Request-Forgery) to understand what CSRF is, the CSRF-Token prevents CSRF.

Comment: And if we have to use multiple ajax requests then it shows 505 internal server error as it change the token value and mismatch. In that case what we need to do?

Comment: Sure, but if the feature doesn't work or has to be hacked, how is that a useful outcome?

Comment: the feature work as expected and it does not need to be hacked 
you will face the above problem when you are doing ajax request to web routes 
if you have many ajax requests consider using the api routes, routes/api.php you won't need to validate csrf for it, csrf token basically prevent requests from forms outside your site to the web routes, which is very good from a security perspective

Comment: @tkausl -  How can i disable it in app/http/Kernel.php in the "api" middleware group? I am using Laravel 5.7 for mobile apis but when i use post api request, system returns "Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again." which means system is applying session based CSRF, how can i avoid it? Please suggest.

Comment: Note that disabling it may be required in some situations. Of course only for development, no way in production. In dev I use more laravel apps on the same local domain in subdir e.g. http://domain.local/laravel-app1/ + http://domain.local/laravel-app2/ In this case I can not use both app in the browser because of CSRF mismatch which leads to bothering error 219 page has expired. It is interesting that laravel has no solution if someone wants to use two different laravel apps on the same domain in production with CSRF enabled. I think that CSRF cookie name and header should be configurable.

Answer (score 7):

The CSRF token protects your application and it's users against cross-site request forgery. For more information on that, have a read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

The token is validated via Middleware in Laravel. If you take a look at the file `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`, you will see it gives you the option to add URLs that should be exempt from CSRF verification.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
    ];
}
```

If you want to disable it entirely, you can remove it from the Middleware group named `web` in `app/Http/Kernel.php`. Those are the middlewares that fire by default over HTTP requests.

I wouldn't recommend disabling it where possible though.

Comment: Note that disabling it may be required in some situations. Of course only for development, no way in production. In dev I use more laravel apps on the same local domain in subdir e.g. domain.local/laravel-app1 + domain.local/laravel-app2 In this case I can not use both app in the browser because of CSRF mismatch which leads to bothering error 219 page has expired. It is interesting that laravel has no solution if someone wants to use two different laravel apps on the same domain in production with CSRF enabled. I think that CSRF cookie name and header should be configurable.

Answer (score 2):

Hi just go to app/Http/Kernel.php file simply commented out line no 31

```
// \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

Comment: You shall not disable this.

Comment: you should never do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block **csrf** token verification easily head over to `app/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` to disable it for all routes
`protected $except = ['*'];` 
or specify routes like this

```
 protected $except = ['/api/route/one', 'api/route/two'];
```

Answer (score 0):

> (**Temporary fix. Not Recommended**)

Just Open kernel.php (app/http)
and disable

```
App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

Comment: Please don't ever do this

Comment: @simonhamp could you explain it in brief why should not do like this, it will worth info. to other users too.

Comment: CSRF token generation and verification is a solid mitigation against a common attack vector - it helps to stop your web forms from being abused by other sites. The most common case is someone brute forcing login attempts against your login form - with a CSRF token in place and this middleware turned on, this becomes unfeasible as an attack vector. Disabling it site-wide like this opens up more opportunities for your forms to be abused. It's **very** risky. Better to set explicit exceptions in the middleware using the `$except` array as noted in other answers.

Comment: It is totally legit to have have security features during development turned off.

Comment: Note that disabling it may be required in some situations. Of course only for development, no way in production. In dev I use more laravel apps on the same local domain in subdir e.g. domain.local/laravel-app1 + domain.local/laravel-app2 In this case I can not use both app in the browser because of CSRF mismatch which leads to bothering error 219 page has expired. It is interesting that laravel has no solution if someone wants to use two different laravel apps on the same domain in production with CSRF enabled. I think that CSRF cookie name and header should be configurable.

Comment: @Fusion That is a very bold claim. CSRF should be integrated into all of your forms, and if you disable it you are not going to prepare your code to work with it. Then you'll push it into production and everything suddenly breaks. Your code should be able to work with CSRF from the very beginning.

Comment: @simonhamp If your authentication is based on tokens stored using localStorage and not cookies, than you can disable CSRF

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad No. This has almost nothing to do with authentication. It's about which clients you authorise to make requests against your application. Without a CSRF token - which is a proof generated *by* your application and handed to a client, that if missing or incorrect on the next request, indicates that the client is potentially untrusted - you are leaving your application open to random clients making unsolicited requests to any endpoint. How that client chooses to store and send the CSRF is entirely up to that client, but your application MUST generate and validate the token