# Disabled CSRF token Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I build 1 service to study by `Laravel`,
but when I test `POST` request, I can't send CSRF to server because my friends use `WinForms`, `Android`, `Angular` so, i want to disabled it or if you have any solutions for me please tell me.

In file VerifyCsrfToken.php (app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php)

I try add '/*' or 'api/article/create' to $except

I got 500 Internal Server Error, if i keep original file VerifyCsrfToken.php, i got 419 error (I using https://www.hurl.it)

This is my route
[my route image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q96L.png)
Please help me,
Thank you.

Comment: Try to add / at the start like this /api/article/create. Because you have prefix /.

Comment: _"I got 500 Internal Server Error"_ - Check your servers error log to get the actual error message. In your local environment, you can also set `display_errors` to On in your php.ini.

Comment: Please follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806762/how-to-disable-csrf-token-in-laravel-and-why-we-have-to-disable-it)

Answer (score 0):

Go in your project kernel.php . their is a line

```
 \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

just close it or comment it

Answer (score -2):

You can use Barryvdh Cors

> https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Follow the instructions of above link

At first from your root project you install barryvdh cors using this command

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

For laravel >=5.5 that's all. This package supports Laravel.
If you are using Laravel < 5.5, you also need to add Cors\ServiceProvider to your config/app.php providers array:

```
Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
```

To allow CORS for all your routes, add the HandleCors middleware in the $middleware property of app/Http/Kernel.php class:

```
protected $middleware = [
// ...
\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

If you want to allow CORS on a specific middleware group or route, add the HandleCors middleware to your group:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
       // ...
    ],

    'api' => [
        // ...
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ],
];
```

Now your cors will be disabled

Comment: Do not post link-only answers, Just add a snippet of code how to do that and finally include the link for more information.

Comment: The OP asks about CSRF, not Cors. Those are two completely different things.