# Laravel API not working without CSRF token (and Headers globally messing around with me)

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to setup an API in my Laravel project, which I would like to consume with Javascript in my own project. The API is stateless, thus my understanding was that CRSF tokens become irrelevant when requesting the API. I am encountering the two following issues:

1. when I try sending requests without the X-CSRF-TOKEN header, I get 401 Unauthorized
2. there seem to be a problem with the headers not being properly applied to the response

The requests are made from subdomain client.site.test to subdomain api.site.test . I have made sure CORS is authorized by applying an "InternalCORS" middleware to my API routes.

*Middleware - applied to all API routes*

```
class InternalCors {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  https://client.site.test');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  GET, POST, PUT');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

*API routes*

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/testApi', function (Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request->user()->fullName(), 200);
})->name('testApi');
```

*Ajax query*

```
window.$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    },
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.site.test/testApi',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.error(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Now, *even* with the middleware explicitely authorizing "Credentials", I was getting a response saying that the header is set not '' instead of 'true'. So I added on top an Nginx directive:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
```

With settings above, the response to the request is "401 Unauthorized". I have doubled checked that the VerifyCsrfToken middleware is only included by default in *web* routes, not *api*.

I would like to able to say that adding the CRSF token to the ajax query solves the issue, **but** it's not that simple.. **There are 3 headers that seem to affect the response I get** :

[CSRF]: whether I send a X-CSRF-TOKEN header in the Ajax request

[MIDD HEADER]: whether I include `header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');` in the middleware for API routes

[NGINX HEADER]: whether I include `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";` in my server configuration for API routes

**Here is a recap of the response to Ajax query, depending on the headers set:**

[CSRF] [MIDD HEADER] <del>[NGINX HEADER]</del> : `value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is ''`

[CSRF] [MIDD HEADER] [NGINX HEADER] : `value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is 'true, true'`

[CSRF] <del>[MIDD HEADER]</del> [NGINX HEADER] : `200 - John Smith`

<del>[CSRF]</del> [MIDD HEADER] <del>[NGINX HEADER]</del> : `value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is ''`

<del>[CSRF]</del> [MIDD HEADER] [NGINX HEADER] : `401 Unauthorized`

<del>[CSRF]</del> <del>[MIDD HEADER]</del> [NGINX HEADER] : `value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is ''`

I'm at a loss here...

Comment: Do you want to disable the csrf token ?

Comment: If your problem is en dev enviroment maybe this could help?
I solved a access-crontol problem with an angular app and API communications in local env. So i used this plug-in and it solved, but is not hte good way 4 sure.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Sorry i cant help you more than this...

Comment: Thanks Oscar - however this plugin seems to tackle the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header, which I have no issue with, my problem arises from the "Allow-Credentials" header

Answer (score 1):

You can Disable CSRF on few routes by editing.

```
App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken
```

and add your own routes name in protected

```
$except = [] array.
```

You can check more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806762/how-to-disable-csrf-token-in-laravel-and-why-we-have-to-disable-it)

Comment: Thanks Vinod but why would the VerifyCsrfToken middleware apply to my API routes as I haven't included it in the API middleware stack?

Comment: By default, all routes are included. You need to exclude that as per your use case.