# datatables do not want to extract data from the API

Tags: javascript, database, laravel, api, datatables

This is my first time trying datatables. I want to display data from the API, this method is get but the data doesn't want to appear and only comes out **"loading"**

**My script**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#data-table').DataTable({  
           "ajax"     : "127.0.0.1:8080/api/v2/client/vendor",  
           "type"     : "GET",
           "columns"     :     [  
                {     "data"     :     "id"     },  
                {     "data"     :     "name"},  
                {     "data"     :     "class"}  
           ]  
      });  
 });
```

**My response API**

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": misry,
            "class": 115

        },
        {
           "id": 2,
            "name": ahmad,
            "class": 76
        },
```

Comment: try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806762/how-to-disable-csrf-token-in-laravel-and-why-we-have-to-disable-it) for removing csrf token from route

Comment: what type of error now you getting? @Vandy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try..please add csrf token

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var table = $('#data-table').DataTable({  
           "processing": true,
           "serverSide": true,
           "ajax"     : "127.0.0.1:8080/api/v2/client/vendor",  
           "type"     : "post",
           "data": function ( d ) {
                    d._token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

                },
           "columns"     :     [  
                {"data":"id"},  
                {"data":"name"},  
                {"data":"class"}  
           ]  
      });  
 });
```

Comment: i don't use token,because method get

Comment: you must use `POST` method in datatable

Answer (score 1):

You can import the Datatables facade.

```
 use Datatables;
```

create a method to display our view and a method that will process our datatables ajax request and Controller look like that

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;

class DatatablesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Displays datatables front end view
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return view('datatables.index');
    }

    /**
     * Process datatables ajax request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function anyData()
    {
        return Datatables::of(User::query())->make(true);
    }
}
```

Let's create our View And Script Ajex Call

```
@push('scripts')
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{!! route('datatables.data') !!}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                { data: 'class', name: 'class' }
            ]
        });
    });



         </script>
     @endpush
```

Register datatables routes in app\Htpp\routes.php

```
Route::controller('datatables', 'DatatablesController', [
    'anyData'  => 'datatables.data',
    'getIndex' => 'datatables',
]);
```