# How to make work laravel, vue session csrf

Tags: laravel, vue.js, csrf

Laravel forms need csrf to work

If i make spa, single page application, with vue+laravel so that my laravel template contains only empty html and body, 
and user doesn't actually refresh the page at all during many hours of working with app,
(page does not refresh because everything is with ajax)

How do I get to keep the login session alive ?
How do I get the csrf to work ? Or can i disable it ?
The application does nothing without login first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806762/how-to-disable-csrf-token-in-laravel-and-why-we-have-to-disable-it

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/airlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using axios with Vue2 for your ajax requests csrf is already available in bootstrap.js, you could see there this line

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
```

If you want to insist for  your ajax only, then you would have put this line in your mounted hook.

```
mounted() {
    this.csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
},
```

this csrfToken should be attaached in your forms like this one

```
<form :method="method.toUpperCase() == 'GET' ? 'GET' : 'POST'">
    <input-hidden :value="csrfToken" name="_token"/>

    <input-hidden
        v-if="['GET', 'POST'].indexOf(method.toUpperCase()) === -1"
        :value="method"
        name="_method"
    />

    <!--
        This hidden submit button accomplishes 2 things:
            1: Allows the user to hit "enter" while an input field is focused to submit the form.
            2: Allows a mobile user to hit "Go" in the on-screen keyboard to submit the form.
    -->
    <input type="submit" class="absolute invisible z-0">

    <slot/>
</form>
```

for good example of it. check this out [csrf token](https://gist.github.com/calebporzio/ae2d46ce2f270d2764a79fa4822a2c80)

**Note:** Please don't disable csrf token cause it's only your way to secure your requests to the server.

Comment: If my vuea app is single page, and the page really doesn't never refresh, do i need and if yes, how do i update the new csrfToken into my form ?