# How to prevent automated requests to my Laravel/Lumen api?

Tags: php, laravel, api, backend, lumen

So, I intend to completely separate my back-end from my front-end. I am learning about Laravel/Lumen API and I intend to return my database data in JSON format to be used by my front-end developers.

I have read several similar threads on Stack Overflow and watched some YouTube videos. Most of them suggested that I should generate a token for "authorized" users. However, the problem is that my project does not have a login system. All of my users are guest users. So, I can't first authorize a person and then generate a token for them.

From what I have understood (which could be flawed), Laravel API follows a RESTful system. So, it is stateless and I can't use CSRF token to check if a request comes from a submitted form and it is not automated. So, what other options do I have?

The reason that I want to separate automated requests from requests coming from forms is that sometimes I have to do heavy processing on some requests and I don't want an automated script to send mass requests and causes a DOS attack.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Although this might not be the answer you were looking for, rate limiting is an option. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#rate-limiting And to say the least, laravel implements this by default.

Comment: That stuff is handled by Laravel for you. Do read about rate-limiting from the above reply .

Comment: @user3532758 Actually, that does sound like what I am looking for. Thank you. The only problem is that the documentation doesn't explain enough how this rate-limitation is handled. How does Laravel check that a guest user has sent too many requests? Is it by IP address? Is it by a cookie/session? What if the automated script deletes the session cookie every time?

Comment: You can except crsf tokens on automated requests. [This might help You](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806762/how-to-disable-csrf-token-in-laravel-and-why-we-have-to-disable-it)

Comment: @stressedout If I'm not mistaken, laravel uses IP.

Comment: laravel uses ip for rate limitation, remember, it's stateless so no cookie/session is expected by definition. you can also put the heavy load request behind authentification wich will limit its access

Comment: @user3532758
Thanks. I believe that does answer my question. Please feel free to post it as an answer. I will appreciate it if you can extend your answer a little bit too. Thank you.

Comment: @N69S Thanks. But if so, shouldn't Laravel store IP addresses and the number of times they accessed the API? Where does Laravel or Lumen store such information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rate limiting can help prevent automated scripts. Laravel has this implemented by default via the Throttle middleware. Default throttle is 60:1, `throttle:60,1`, translating to throttle if 60 attempts are registered within 1 minute.

This middleware is applied to all routes, however, you can override this for individual routes and define custom values for number of attempts and time. Following example adapted from documentation configures the route to throttle if there's 30 attempts within 1 minute:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api', 'throttle:30,1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function () {
        //
    });
});
```

There are other configuration options, please do refer to the documentation for more information on that.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#rate-limiting

> How does Laravel check that a guest user has sent too many requests?

In very basic terms, Laravel keeps track of hits on a particular endpoint/domain by a particular IP in the application cache. The request domain and the IP are used as the cache key. Every time an endpoint is hit, no of attempts, stored in the cache, is incremented. If the no of attempts reaches the maximum number of allowed attempts within the time window specified in the `throttle` config applied on the route, that IP will be locked out for a while.

Attempts are automatically cleared if there's no new hit in the time window.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I understand it correctly, if a user reaches the maximum limit, assuming that our throttle is set to 60 request per 1 minute, then the user will not be able to access the API for another 1 minute. Am I right? Also, your middleware is using auth:api. If I have no authentication system, I should drop that part and use only the throttle part?

Comment: Yes and yes, .You can drop auth if you do not need it.