# Limiting Page Refresh on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to limit logged-in user from refreshing a certain page multiple-times (e.g. repeated pressing of F5 key). Is there any other simpler way other than counting the number of refresh and saving it on the database like this?

```
public function myPage()
{
    // Page is a table storing refresh count of pages
    $page = Page::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    $refresh_count = $page->refresh_count;
    
    if($refresh_count > 10){
       // logout user
    }else{
        $refresh_count = $page->refresh_count + 1;
        $page->update(['refresh_count' => $refresh_count]);
    }
    return view('mypage');
}
```

Comment: use throttle middleware

Comment: As @alzafan said, throttle is the way to go. If you want a summary of how throttle works:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637524/how-to-prevent-automated-requests-to-my-laravel-lumen-api/63638405#63638405

Comment: I've tried it and it works! They page throws an error after exceeding the limit. How can I access the page again? It's not stated in the documentation

Comment: It will be throttled for 1 minute; it's mentioned in the SO link I shared :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Throttle middleware to limit access to a route or page refreshing.

The throttle middleware accepts two parameters that determine the maximum number of requests that can be made in a given number of minutes. For example, let's specify that an authenticated user may access the following group of routes 60 times per minute:

```
Route::middleware('auth', 'throttle:60,1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function () {
        //
    });
});
```

For more details [see documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#rate-limiting)