# Disable or remove CSRF tags & header in laravel 8 API responses

Tags: laravel-8, csrf-token

I have been working with doing login/registration between an Ionic 4 application and laravel 8 using passport. I am having a recurring problem of CSRF token header always being added to the response which causes a problem in Ionic because the expected response is JSON and the headers cause a HttpErrorResponse JSON syntax error when I try to read the response.

Any advice on how I can solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable CSRF Token in Laravel and why we have to disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806762/how-to-disable-csrf-token-in-laravel-and-why-we-have-to-disable-it)

Comment: Hi @MeherUllahKhanRaj , I tried changing the except option to ['*'] and also entering the route directly in VerifyCsrfToken.php but the response still has the headers and returns in the format <!-- CSRF Token -->
<!--
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/file-manager/js/file-manager.js') }}"></script>
-->
{"message":"Successfully created user!"}